# How to choose an associate editor for my manuscript?

Tags: publications, editors, journal-workflow

I want to submit my manuscript to a journal.

It is written that I need to choose an associate editor for my paper and if the associate editor whom I assign rejects my paper,
I cannot resubmit my paper to the same journal with another associate editor of the same journal.

So the question boils down how to effectively choose the associate editor and assign my paper to him?

What are the things to keep in mind while choosing an associate editor for my manuscript?

Is it possible that wrong choice of associate editor can lead to rejection of paper? Or is it possible that even if I choose an associate editor who is not an expert in my field he may send my paper to the appropriate associate editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question boils down how to effectively choose the associate editor and assign my paper to him?

The associate editor (AE) has to first decide if the paper is worth reviewing for the journal (they can often do a summary reject if the quality of the work is low). If it is, they then have to select the reviewers for your paper, get the decision from the reviewers, and then use that to make a recommendation. So, ideally you'd prefer someone who is:

1. familiar with your area and work,
2. familiar with people who would be good reviewers for your paper,
3. someone that you or your co-authors get along with.

Getting #1 is hardest - most journals don't have AEs in every sub-area of a field. As an AE I often handle paper that are in related fields so I know of possible reviewers, even if I'm not an expert in the field myself.

For #3 you can't have someone too close to you (e.g. someone that a co-author regularly publishes with), and you also don't want someone with whom one of your co-authors has very poor relations (e.g. fundamental disagreements about the field).

Note that while you may recommend an AE to the editor when submitting a paper, the editor has the final say on the AE that is selected for the paper.

With regard to your other questions:

> Is it possible that wrong choice of associate editor can lead to rejection of paper?

It is always possible (eg if the AE doesn't like the line of research or chooses poor reviewers), but there are many factors that can lead to the rejection as well, and it is almost impossible to control for all of them.

> Or is it possible that even if I choose an associate editor who is
>   not an expert in my field he may send my paper to the appropriate
>   associate editor?

The editor may do this if the AE is busy or if the editor thinks that someone else can handle the paper well. It would be more rare for an AE to  ask for a paper to be sent to someone else.

Comment: Re #3: but that someone also shouldn't be *too* close to you or your co-authors, to avoid conflicts of interest.

Comment: One question : Is it possible that wrong choice of Associate Editor can lead to rejection of paper

Comment: @Learnmore Unfortunately, there are many factors out of your control that could lead to the rejection of your paper. But, even though you indicate a preferred AE, this doesn't mean that they will be assigned the paper. The editors of the journal may override your suggestion if that AE has too high a workload or for other reasons.

Comment: @Anyon That as well - I was more thinking the other way of avoiding someone who doesn't like your work or who you've had disagreements with in the past. But, both are valid concerns.